# GSON.fromJson nested Java Objects

Tags: java, android, facebook, gson

I am trying to make updates to my android app to accomodate the recent facebook changes with pictures. Previously i just got a string back for the user photo but not its returning an array. I have updated my code but the data is just coming back null, can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

GSON call

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
FBFriendResponse resp = gson.fromJson(response, FBFriendResponse.class);
```

New facebook data structure

```
"picture": {
    "data": {
       "url": "######.jpg",
       "is_silhouette": false
    }
 }


public class FBFriend implements Comparable<FBFriend>
{
    public String id, name, gender;
    public FBFriendPicture picture;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(FBFriend another) {
        return this.name.compareTo(another.name);       
    }

}
public class FBFriendPicture 
{
    public FBFriendPictureData pictureData;
}

public class FBFriendPictureData 
{
    public String friendPictureURL;
    public Boolean friendPictureIssilhouette;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. It was due to the wrong names used in the classes

```
public class FBFriend implements Comparable<FBFriend>
{
    public String id, name, gender;
    public FBFriendPicture picture;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(FBFriend another) {
        return this.name.compareTo(another.name);       
    }

}
public class FBFriendPicture 
{
    public FBFriendPictureData data;
}

public class FBFriendPictureData 
{
    public String url;
    public Boolean is_silhouette;
}
```